# border-radius: x x x x - support

Tags: html, css

I have just found out that it is possible to declare the radius for every corner like `border-radius: 10px 20px 30px 40px;` instead of declaring every single one individually. I would like to know if the support for this is restricted.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

Comment: No it's not...individual radii have always been available. In fact there are 8 radii that can be stated, not just 4 as you can make each corner elliptical - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: @Paulie_D Yup just like `border-radius: x x x x / x x x x;`, I've found that out as well :) I just needed to know if there are any issues in other browsers. Thanks you two for the quick answer(s)!

Answer (score 0):

You can check it here:

```
<img src="GemsIconGif.gif" width="42" height="42" alt="Test" style="border-color:Gray; border-bottom:1px; border-left:1px; border-right:1px; border-top:4px; border-width:5px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 15px 10px 6px 25px;"/>
```

Here i give inline css like:

```
border-radius: 15px 10px 6px 25px;
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aqoaLjc1/4/)

Also Check [Div border Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aqoaLjc1/5/)